# Can I specify format Spark-Redshift uses to load to S3?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

Specifically when I'm reading from an existing `Redshift` table, how can I specify the format it will use during the load to the temporary directory?

My load looks like this:

```
data = spark.read.format('com.databricks.spark.redshift') \
            .option('url', REDSHIFT_URL_DEV) \
            .option('dbtable', 'ods_misc.requests_2014_04') \
            .option('tempdir', REDSHIFT_WEBLOG_DIR + '/2014_04') \
            .load()
```

When I look at the data from the default load it looks like `csv` where it splits the columns across multiple files, so for example `col1` `col2`... are in `0000_part1` and so on.